# Удаление сообщени выбранного пользователя из SelectUser

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

```py
viewuser = View(timeout=120)

selectuser = nextcord.ui.UserSelect(placeholder="Выберите пользователя...", min_values=1, max_values=1) 

async def selectuser_callback(interaction):
     await interaction.response.send_message("Очистка сообщений завершена2.", ephemeral=True)
     selected_user_id = interaction.data['values'][0]

     selected_user = await self.bot.fetch_user(selected_user_id)


     channel = self.bot.get_channel(interaction.channel_id)
     await channel.purge(limit=amount, check=lambda m: m.author.id == selected_user_id)
```

• Как должно работать: После аыборо пользователя удаляется указанное число сообщений каторые отправил указанный пользователь в SelectUser.

• Ошибки в терминале : Нету.

• Предпологаямая ошибка : я не правильно указываю пользователя в удаление сообщений.

• Буду раз помощи.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Щяс нормально??